# I can easily append dictionary items but how do I append class items?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd much rather use classes to manage things like user profiles, etc.,  however, I'm not clear on how to simply *append* new users to a list of class instances ... With dictionaries you'd simply:

```
new_item = {
   "ID": 0,
   "Name": "Test",
}
list.append(new_item)
```

How might I achieve this same thing with a list of user profiles that are class instances, not dictionaries?

Thank you!!

Comment: I don't understand what makes you think that custom class instances would work any different than dict class instances in this context

Comment: @DeepSpace Novice Python programmers frequently don't understand that the classes, modules, etc. that they create are first-class objects and can be used in the exactly the same way as builtins.

Comment: @BoarGules Fair enough, but I do expect them to at least *try* first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly the same way:

```
new_object=MyClass(id=0, name="Test")
mylist.append(new_object)
```

And *please* don't use `list` as a variable name. It will come back to bite you if you do.

Comment: This is awesome!!  Thank you.